# Javascript groupby and sum key value

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of dicts

```
var response = [{
        "ShoppingCart": "cart1",
        "Class": "Gen",
        "Type": "300",
        "SubClass": "Mens",
        "Points": 0.9
    },
    {
        "ShoppingCart": "cart2",
        "Class": "Lux",
        "Type": "3002C",
        "SubClass": "Mens",
        "Points": 0.75
    },
    {
        "ShoppingCart": "cart3",
        "Class": "Lux",
        "Type": "380",
        "SubClass": "Ladies",
        "Points": 0.5
    },
    {
        "ShoppingCart": "cart4",
        "Class": "Lux",
        "Type": "300",
        "SubClass": "Cabin",
        "Points": 1
    },
    {
        "ShoppingCart": "cart5",
        "Class": "Comfort",
        "Type": "380",
        "SubClass": "Ladies",
        "Points": 1
    },
    {
        "ShoppingCart": "cart6",
        "Class": "Gen",
        "Type": "380",
        "SubClass": "Cabin",
        "Points": 0.9
    },
    {
        "ShoppingCart": "cart7",
        "Class": "Gen",
        "Type": "300",
        "SubClass": "Cabin",
        "Points": 0.7
    },
    {
        "ShoppingCart": "cart8",
        "Class": "Gen",
        "Type": "380PC",
        "SubClass": "Ladies",
        "Points": 0.7
    },
    {
        "ShoppingCart": "cart9",
        "Class": "Lux",
        "Type": "380",
        "SubClass": "Cabin",
        "Points": 0.5
    },
    {
        "ShoppingCart": "cart10",
        "Class": "Lux",
        "Type": "380",
        "SubClass": "Ladies",
        "Points": 0.5
    }
]
```

I am using reduce function and When i do a groupby and sum the Points , the Class is repeated and not unique , How can i perform a groupby and sum the unique values .
I know lodash's groupby function solves, how can i do it with the reduce function itself ?
The last Class comfort is not coming in the output , why is that ?

the code so far

```
result = [];

response.reduce(function(res, value) {
    if (!res[value.Type]) {
        res[value.Type] = { Type: value.Type, Class: value.Class, Points: 0 };
        result.push(res[value.Type])
    }
    res[value.Type].Points += parseFloat(value.Points);
    return res;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

result:

```
[
  { Type: '300', Class: 'Gen', Points: 2.5999999999999996 },
  { Type: '3002C', Class: 'Lux', Points: 0.75 },
  { Type: '380', Class: 'Lux', Points: 3.4 },
  { Type: '380PC', Class: 'Gen', Points: 0.7 }
]
```

expected result:

```
[
  { Type: '300', Class: 'Gen', Points: 2.5999999999999996 },
  { Type: '3002C', Class: 'Lux', Points: 0.75 },
  { Type: '380', Class: 'Lux', Points: 3.4 },
  { Type: '380PC', Class: 'Gen', Points: 0.7 },
  { Type: '380', Class: 'Comfort', Points: 1 }
]
```

What am i missing in this reduce function ?

Modified Code as per epascarello's suggestions

```
response.reduce(function(res, value) {
    const key = value.Type + "-" + value.Class;
    if (!res[key]) {
        res[key] = { Type: value.Type, Class: value.Class, Points: 0 };
        result.push(res[key])
    }
    res[key].Points += parseFloat(value.Points);
    return res;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I made it runnable and your "result" does not match what the code outputs

Comment: sorry i made a mistake in my code, i have corrected it as you mentioned earlier, but the result is not still coming as expected

Comment: ANd you just removed the runnable code....

Comment: Well if you have two Types that match, you need to make your key be based off two things, not one.

Comment: You are correct, i need it to be grouped on two keys, as you mentioned the result outputs for some of the type and class, but one class 'Comfort' is missing

Comment: Because it is groped with Lux. Make a composite key using the two properties.

Comment: You're only ever grouping by `Type`, never by `Class`.

Comment: oh so the second part of the code block is not executed and i need to make a composite key of Type and Class together ?

Comment: You are working at a movie theater. You ask four guys where their first name is. They say Frank. You look up the seating chart for Frank. You shove them all into the same seat because you only use their first name. You need to use their first name and last name to know who they are and where to put them.

Comment: got it , modifying the code with your recommendation

Comment: i have modified the code but now its not adding the values, instead its showing all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more what you're looking for.

Basically, for each item in `response` it will try to find an item in the results array that has the same `Type` and `Class` as the provided item. If it finds one it will increment that item's `Points` by the provided `Points`, if not it will append a new item onto the results array.

`.reduce` is a very useful function, but how you had it before was not utilizing its capabilities.

```js
var response = [{
    "ShoppingCart": "cart1",
    "Class": "Gen",
    "Type": "300",
    "SubClass": "Mens",
    "Points": 0.9
  },
  {
    "ShoppingCart": "cart2",
    "Class": "Lux",
    "Type": "3002C",
    "SubClass": "Mens",
    "Points": 0.75
  },
  {
    "ShoppingCart": "cart3",
    "Class": "Lux",
    "Type": "380",
    "SubClass": "Ladies",
    "Points": 0.5
  },
  {
    "ShoppingCart": "cart4",
    "Class": "Lux",
    "Type": "300",
    "SubClass": "Cabin",
    "Points": 1
  },
  {
    "ShoppingCart": "cart5",
    "Class": "Comfort",
    "Type": "380",
    "SubClass": "Ladies",
    "Points": 1
  },
  {
    "ShoppingCart": "cart6",
    "Class": "Gen",
    "Type": "380",
    "SubClass": "Cabin",
    "Points": 0.9
  },
  {
    "ShoppingCart": "cart7",
    "Class": "Gen",
    "Type": "300",
    "SubClass": "Cabin",
    "Points": 0.7
  },
  {
    "ShoppingCart": "cart8",
    "Class": "Gen",
    "Type": "380PC",
    "SubClass": "Ladies",
    "Points": 0.7
  },
  {
    "ShoppingCart": "cart9",
    "Class": "Lux",
    "Type": "380",
    "SubClass": "Cabin",
    "Points": 0.5
  },
  {
    "ShoppingCart": "cart10",
    "Class": "Lux",
    "Type": "380",
    "SubClass": "Ladies",
    "Points": 0.5
  }
];

var grouped = response.reduce((res, value) => {
  const ext = res.find(({
    Type,
    Class
  }) => {
    return Type === value.Type && Class === value.Class;
  });

  if (ext) {
    ext.Points += value.Points;
  } else {
    res.push({
      Type: value.Type,
      Class: value.Class,
      Points: value.Points
    });
  }

  return res;
}, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is exactly what i am looking, I would really appreciate a little context on whats happening in your code.

Answer (score 2):

So make your key based off the two properties, not just one

```
const key = value.Type + "-" + value.Class;
if (!res[key]) {
```